# Share consumer in an Akka-Stream while retaining Kafka's partition rebalancing-functionality

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream

In my application, we're creating a lot of streams and a lot of consumers (one per stream). I'm trying to use only one consumer for all of our streams. I did that like this:

```
Consumer
  .committableExternalSource(
    consumer, Subscriptions.assignment(new TopicPartition("topic", 0), group, 50.seconds)
  )
```

The problem here is that I don't want to assign the partition manually. I want to be able to pass the consumer but use Kafka's automatic partition assignments. So I tried this way:

```
Consumer
  .plainPartitionedSource(KafkaConfigurations.consumerSettings(group), Subscriptions.topics("topic"))
  .map {
    case (topicPartition, source) =>
      Consumer
        .committableExternalSource(consumer, Subscriptions.assignment(topicPartition), group, 50.seconds)
  }.flatMapMerge(10, identity)
```

However, I guess that I still would be creating a consumer per source when using the `plainPartitionedSource`, so, the question is if it's possible to achieve using this or a similar approach or if I'll have to create a different (custom) implementation for this use case.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue - in order to share the consumer, the partition has to be assigned manually for some reason. 
Where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?